# Search bar after click

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, searchbar

I'm trying to place a search button next the nav menu that when clicked it pops up the search bar bellow the nav menu. Basically would be something like the following pictures:

**Normal State**

[image]

**After Click**
[image]

Is there any tutorials out there that might help me achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest jQuery, but there might be a way to use CSS for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $ ("#searchForm"). hide ();
  $("#searchButton").click(function(){
       $("#searchForm").show();
  }); 
});
```

**HTML:**
`<form id="searchForm">myForm</form>
<input type="submit" id="searchButton"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with only CSS.

Personally I would use `position: relative` on the menu and then `position: absolute` on the search-bar. Put `right: 10px` and `bottom: -100px` (change pixels to height of search bar).  The search-bar HTML should be inside of the menu.

---

To sum it up, to menu you will add the following css:

```
position: relative;
```

To search-bar you will add the following css:

```
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
bottom: -100px;
```

Where `100px` is height of search-bar.